# Storing API address in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I'm writing an HTML site which will use jQuery to interact with an API.

I've built the api already (Web api controllers)
The site has around 25 pages. Each of these will have some functionality that will depend on an API call (gets / posts) to some degree.

What I've found is Currently in each of the included script pages, I'm writing the full API address. The biggest issue is that if i change servers that the API is hosted on, that is 25 updates to an API address.
I thought of throwing it into local Storage/ Session and just referencing it from that so it only has to be physically written in 1 spot, then could just be appended to the relevant section.

But maybe HTML has some functionality i'm unfamiliar with (or jQuery) for that matter that is a better option than session/local storage?

I know that with references to another JS file you can get the values from it, but i don't like the potential performance impact of loading another JS file to get an API address. So does HTML have a better option for this?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide us example of the code you are using? It will help us provide a better answer. General answer  to your question is, this cannot be solved with HTML. If you use JavaScript on your pages, you might wanna try and use something like a variable, that contains a string that is your API domain name or the part of your API address that's common for all pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your apiBaseUrl in an localstorage by setting the below and get the same item and use throughout your application

localStorage.setItem("apiBaseUrl","your_api_url_here");

and to get the same item

var apiUrl = localStorage.getItem("apiBaseUrl");

But if you are building a realtime application i would suggest you to not to go with this solutuion. And you can have constant in config or somewhere so that you can call the same everywhere and use. something like below and you don't need to change the base url everywhere. All you need to do is using the constant. And tomorrow if you want to change the baseUrl, you just need to change in one place.

- *config.js*

const baseApiUrl = your_api_base_url;

and just use baseApiUrl

Comment: wow i don't know how it didn't occur to me to have a basically empty js file with the api address in it and just reference that file multiple times throughout the site. I'm dumb. thanks

Comment: check if you are using any specific framework, just follow the way they do.. And if you are just using html & Js and have one .js file with some name and add your api url, and you can include this js in your common footer... then you don't need to include it in all the files.. Hope this works for you....